# Security risks of opening firewall for ssh access from internal to DMZ

Tags: security, ssh, firewall

I have a server in our internal network, and there are files/reports on that server that I need to get to a box in our DMZ. They aren't served up directly from the box in the DMZ; they are processed by the server and displayed to the user through a portal application. So I was going to use ssh and key-pairs to do it.

We have this setup with other boxes, but I wanted to see if there were any (I guess there are always some) security risks with allowing a connection from an internal box to connect to a DMZ box using ssh. I can't think of any easy way someone in the DMZ would be able to exploit this rule (the firewall would only allow connections from INTERNAL to DMZ, not the other way around) if ssh is setup correctly on the DMZ box, but I don't do security as a career and was wondering if there might be anything I'm missing. Thoughts and comments are appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the rule allows the connection from INTERNAL to DMZ and not the other way around, this seems perfectly sensible to me.

You have to be able to manage your machines on DMZ after all, and the login credentials are moving over the network encrypted too, so that's not a problem.